# IIS URL Rewrite Rules for Subdomain Routing in ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, multi-tenant, url-rewrite-module

I have a web application written in ASP.NET MVC 5 which contains information about its users. Now I would like to create a profile page for each of the users accessible as a subdomain of my web site (e.g. `user1.example.com`, `user2.example.com`, ...).

I want these subdomains to be accessible over HTTP, while the rest of the application must require HTTPS to be used.

I run the web application on IIS so i figured it would be best if I used URL Rewrite rules to rewrite `user1.example.com` to `example.com/Profile/Index?name=user1`, so the web application itself wouldn't have to know about subdomains being used. I came up with these rewrite rules:

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <clear />
    <rule name="Rewrite user subdomains into query string" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^(.+)" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" negate="true" pattern="^www\.example\.com$" />
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^([^.]+)\.example\.com$" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="/Profile/Index?name={C:1}" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="Redirect to https without www" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions trackAllCaptures="false">
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www\.example\.com$" />
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^example\.com$" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://example.com/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

This code unfortunately does not rewrite `user1.example.com` to `example.com/Profile/Index?name=user1` and forces HTTPS even over `user1.example.com`.

Would someone please explain to me why and how could this be fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using this code:

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <clear />
    <rule name="Rewrite url with tenant subdomain" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^$" /> <!-- So resources like user1.example.com/Content/css wouldn't be affested by this rewrite -->
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" negate="true" pattern="^www\.example\.com$" />
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^([^.]+)\.example\.com$" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="Profile/Index?subdomain={C:1}" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="Redirect to www.example.com" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)"/>
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^example\.com$"/>
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.example.com/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="Redirect to https" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.example.com/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

What had me confused was the fact, that Url helpers in Index template started to throw `System.Web.HttpException: Cannot use a leading .. to exit above the top directory.` Since it's the only page I need to have tenant specific, I gave up, hardcoded the links and everything started working fine.